# How to move a custom added tab(say x) under 'description' tab in a single product page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a custom tab called 'Expert Review' beside my description tab into the product page. Now I want to move this expert review tab to show under the description tab.

I have tried this to do this:

// Remove tab

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', function( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['Expert Review'] );
    return $tabs;
}, 98 );

// Insert tab into description tab

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', function( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['description']['callback'] = function() {
        global $product;
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
        if ( $product && ( $product->has_attributes() || apply_filters( 'wc_product_enable_dimensions_display', $product->has_weight() || $product->has_dimensions() ) ) ) {
            wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/additional-information.php' );
        }
    };
    return $tabs;
}, 98 );


But it is not happening for me.

Code I used to create the Custom 'Expert Review' tab:

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Expert Review', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: You can't add a tab inside a product tab in WooCommerce… What you can do is reorder tabs items using the 'priority' argument. Or you can also append some custom content to an existing product tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the follows code snippet to achieve your task -

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'modify_woocommerce_product_tabs' );
function modify_woocommerce_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    $descr_priority = $descr_title = '';
    if( isset( $tabs['description'] ) ) {
        $descr_title = $tabs['description']['title'];
        $descr_priority = $tabs['description']['priority'];
        unset( $tabs['description'] );
    }
    $tabs['custom_description'] = array(
        'title'     => $descr_title,
        'priority'  => $descr_priority,
        'callback'  => 'custom_woocommerce_product_description_tab'
    );
    return $tabs;
}

// Display Expert review content under description tab
function custom_woocommerce_product_description_tab() {
    global $product;
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
    // Add your Expert reviews content
    echo '<p>' . __( "Your Expert Review content foes here" ) . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes to your active theme's functions.php